# For fixed square matrix $A$, If ${\bf Tr}(AX) =0$ for all positive definite $X$, is it true $A = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Suppose $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ is fixed. If we have ${\bf Tr}(AX) = 0$ for all real, symmetric, positive definite $X$, does it imply $A=0$?

I think the answer is yes. I tried different nonzero $A$'s, but I can always find an $X$ to which the trace is nonzero.

Comment: Does $X$ have to be symmetric? See the definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map $(C,D)\mapsto \text{Tr}(D^TC)$ is an inner product. For any matrix $X$, write $$X = (X+\lambda I)-\lambda I$$for large enough $\lambda >0$. Then both $(X+\lambda I)$ and $\lambda I$ are positive definite and $$(X,A^T) = \text{Tr}(AX) = \text{Tr}(A(X+\lambda I)) - \text{Tr}(A(\lambda I)) = 0 - 0 = 0.$$ Since $(X,A^T) = 0$ for all $X$, we can choose $X = A^T$ to see that $A^T =0$ and so $A = 0$.